# UseTranslation from react-i18next returns null

Tags: reactjs, i18next

useTranslation() is returning undefined for i18n. I am unable to understand why. I have spent a lot of time in debugging this issue. I will appreciate you help!
[image]

Comment: Please upload your code rather than a picture and also ensure that the bug is reproducible

Answer (score 2):

as I haven't seen your code, sorry, this might be dabbling in the dark.

You need to import some file where you have the customization for the i18n, and where you have the translation strings. Unless you're doing it in Main, not sure where you have that.

i.e.:
`translationUtils.js`

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({

  lng: 'en',
  fallbackLng: 'en',

 resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        "myTranslationKey": "hello world"
      }
    }
  },

  keySeparator: false,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
});

export default i18n;
```

you then need to import that in your file (the one you have in the screenshot) i.e.:

`import './translationUtils';`

and then you should be able to use it like:

```
const {t} = useTranslation();

t("myTranslationKey", "default value");
```

You also need to make sure your version of react supports hooks.